# Execution stops after the first iteration of the outter loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, scope, iteration

```
var array = [5,3,4,1]

for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++){

    for(var y = array.length - 1; y >= x; y--){

        if(array[x] > array[y]){
          var temp = array[y];
          array[y] = array[x];
          array[x] = temp; 
    }
  }
}
console.log(array); 

//Output : [1,3,4,5]
```

I understand the loops are meant to swap the loops are essentially swapping the two values if x is greater than y.

`[1,3,4,5]` is the result when x = 0, but *why doesn't anything change once x = 1, and so on? Shouldn't the secondary for-loop be run thru its iterations and continue to swap the values until the first loop reaches `array.length` (4)?*

EDIT: A bit more information on where my thought process is: 
The output is [1,3,4,5] after the first iteration, but what about when it iterates to x = 1? At that point, x[1] = 3, correct? The if statement fails when y decrements from 5, to 4, to 3, but 3 > 1 and so I would think the output is changed to [3,1,4,5]. At which point x iterates to x[2] which is 4 and the output becomes [4,3,1,5] and finally, x[3] = 5 where no further swaps are possible

Comment: What makes you think it isn't running all the way through? (In this specific example, it doesn't have to because the array is ordered on the very first iteration...)

Comment: My mistake. I know it's running all the way through, I just don't understand why nothing changes after the first iteration.

Comment: Nothing changes because nothing gets passed the if statement. Read through some tutorials about programming, this kinda thing will be in there early on.

Answer (score -1):

Don't understand what you meant by the process stops.  The following is a modified version of your code

```
var array = [5,3,4,1]
var count = 0, swap = 0;
for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
    for(var y = array.length - 1; y >= x; y--){
        count++;
        if(array[x] > array[y]){
          swap++;
          var temp = array[y];
          array[y] = array[x];
          array[x] = temp; 
    }
  }
}
console.log('count', count, 'swap', swap,'array',array);
```

count 10 swap 1 array [1, 3, 4, 5]

The code is a simple swap sort algorithm from smallest to largest.  After the first swap, the array is completely sorted and thus no further swapping occurred.  The loop did ran 10 times.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so dense, but why doesn't any further swapping occur? The output is [1,3,4,5] after the first iteration, but what about when it iterates to x = 1? At that point, x[1] = 3, correct? The if statement fails when y decrements from 5, to 4, to 3, but 3 > 1 and so I would think the output is changed to [3,1,4,5]. At which point x iterates to x[2] which is 4 and the output become [4,3,1,5] and finally, x[3] = 5 where no further swaps are possible.

Comment: When x=1, y = {3,2,1} (not {3,2,1,0}) and array[y] = {5, 4, 3} (again, not {5,4,3,1} since the loop breaks when y < x and x=1).  You can add a print statement(console.log) to show the values of x,y,array[x] and array[y] in the 'for loop' to see.